# (Restore-SPFarm) Search Service backup: Error occurred while processing the log

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, backup, restore, crawl

I want to backup/restore the Search service application from a test farm to a production farm. I performed the classic backup of the service application from Powershell:

```
Backup-SPFarm -Directory C:\Temp -BackupMethod Full -Item "Farm\Shared Services\Shared Services Applications\Search Service"
```

I have then tried to run both **Restore-SPFarm** and restore through Central administration but I get the following error while restoring both **CrawlStore** and **LinksStore** database:

> An error occurred while
>   processing the log for database 'SharePointSearchDB_LinksStore'.  If
>   possible, restore from backup. If a backup is not available, it might
>   be necessary to rebuild the log.

EDIT -> Important additional info: the restore of the databases on the source farm gives **NO errors**. The backup are not damaged, the problem is the restoring of LinksStore and CrawlStore on a **new farm**.

The log looks like:

> [5/18/2015 3:39:30 PM] Progress: [SharePointSearchDB_LinksStore] 100
>   percent complete. [5/18/2015 3:39:35 PM] Verbose:
>   [SharePointSearchDB_LinksStore] SQL Server Message: Processed 3544
>   pages for database 'SharePointSearchDB_LinksStore', file
>   'SharePointSearchDB_LinksStore' on file 1.  [5/18/2015 3:39:35 PM]
>   Verbose: [SharePointSearchDB_LinksStore] SQL Server Message: Processed
>   11208 pages for database 'SharePointSearchDB_LinksStore', file
>   'SharePointSearchDB_LinksStore_log' on file 1.  [5/18/2015 3:39:55 PM]
>   Warning: [SharePointSearchDB_LinksStore] An error occurred while
>   processing the log for database 'SharePointSearchDB_LinksStore'.  If
>   possible, restore from backup. If a backup is not available, it might
>   be necessary to rebuild the log. RESTORE DATABASE is terminating
>   abnormally. [5/18/2015 3:39:55 PM] Debug:
>   [SharePointSearchDB_LinksStore]    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader
>   ds)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
>   Boolean asyncWrite)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Backup.SPSqlBackupRestoreHelper.RunCommand(SqlCommand
>   sqlCommand, SPBackupRestoreInformation args, Boolean throwOnRestart,
>   Boolean& restart, SPSqlBackupRestoreConnection connection) [5/18/2015
>   3:39:55 PM] Warning: [SharePointSearchDB_LinksStore] SQL command
>   failed and needs to be restarted. The command will be re-started a
>   total of three times before throwing an exception.

Admin and **AnalyticsReportingStore** are restored correctly.

Manual backup and restore on **LinksStore** and **CrawlStore** dbs can be performed smoothly on SQL Server and I'm not using any particular backup configuration. What can cause the problem?

Comment: try with a fresh backup...looks like log file corrutped

Comment: Do you have a SQL Server database backup? I'd try those instead if available. (Good Question +1)

Comment: I have an older backup but is not updated as I would need... and I've already tried to re-perform the backup but I'm still getting the same error. But as I was saying, if I perform the backup from SQL and not from SharePoint (Backup-SPFarm), the error doesn't appear!

Comment: Important additional info: trying to restore the potentially damaged backup on the source farm I get NO error. The problem is then in the restoring of LinksStore and CrawlStore on a new farm. But this is a standard procedure from Technet!